# I have installed tensorflow but cannot import in jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow with anaconda successfully. There is a virtual environment named tensorflow, and I activate it.
But in Jupyter Notebook, I tried to import tensorflow, only to get an error: No module named 'tensorflow'.

Comment: Are you running jupyter from the virtual environment too? you need to `activate tensorfow` and then run `jupyter notebook` in there to start Jupyter's server from the right python environment.

Comment: Post the commands you used to create the virtual environment and install tensor flow (in the order you typed them)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: should be `activate tensorflow` and **NOT** `activate tensorfow`